# Git Clone Laravel Website just displays files and directories

Tags: php, git, laravel-5

I'm still really new to Git version control and Laravel.  But I have gotten so far, and I'm not sure now where I am going wrong.

I set up VirtualBox and Vagrant on my local windows machine and installed homestead successfully.  I have managed to get my Laravel website (it's only one page at the moment as I learn things) working correctly, it displays the header and the footer and the images load and everything.  So that's all good.

So now, I have my Laravel website set up within my virtual vagrant server.  On this server, the directory for my website is:

`/home/vagrant/Code/sites/public_html`

No when I `cd` to that directory, I ran the following:

```
git init
get remote add origin https://user@repo/user/publichtml.git
git add *
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git push -u origin master
```

(I've substituted user@repo instead of the real URL)

All went through successfully.  Great.  So now on my live server I ran the following:

```
cd /home/sites/public_html
git init
git clone https://user@repo/user/publichtml.git
```

Which again, worked fine.  It downloaded all the files into the `public_html` directory which is great.  So then I go to visit the website and this is what I get:[image]

The only explanation for this happening is maybe I need to install something on the server before I clone these files to it.  I guess the files in the Laravel folder won't run by themselves? Do I need to install composer and laravel on the server or something? If so, how do I do that, and why don't they run on their own?

I cannot see a .htaccess or index.php in the root directory so I am not sure how it runs anyway.

Comment: You have to create .htaccess file and redirect root to the `public` folder. The index.php is right there

Comment: @AlexSlipknot I dont understand why that isnt done on my homestead server, yet that runs correctly.  That sounds like a workaround and not an actual solution.

Comment: Well, when `.htaccess` is not in the repo you'll meet this problem each time when you cloning your project

Comment: after cloning your repo, just run `composer update` to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should install Laravel using composer instead.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mysite
```

You should also point the document root on your web server to laravels "/public" folder, making the framework code reside *outside* of the document root. That's good for security (no one can access any framework code, like your configs etc directly).

You will then find the `.htaccess`-file in the `/public` folder.

Please read the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation) about the different but recommended ways to install Laravel.

Btw, doesn't homestead use Nginx instead of Apache? In that case, .htaccess isn't even used. Please refer to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead) again regarding homestead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect traffic to `public/index.php` instructions for this are webserver dependent.